# Duplicate in full join trail using mysql with duplicate column name

Tags: mysql, duplicates

my code is like this

```
select * from a left join b on a.t = b.t
UNION
select * from a right join b on a.t = b.t;
```

my result is like this
[restult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81znL.png)

I want the result like this
[result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlH5x.png)

Would anyone help?

my table structures are:

table a:
t   x
-   -
A   1
B   2
C   3

Table B:
t    y
-    -
B    2
C    3
D    4

table_code:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `t` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `x` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('A',1);
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('B',2);
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('C',3);

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `t` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `b` VALUES ('B',2);
INSERT INTO `b` VALUES ('C',3);
INSERT INTO `b` VALUES ('D',4);
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try This Query For Your Expected Result.

```
Select * FROM 
     (SELECT a.t, a.x, b.y FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.t = b.t
      UNION ALL
     SELECT b.t, a.x, b.y FROM a RIGHT JOIN b ON a.t = b.t WHERE a.t IS NULL) A 
ORDER BY A.t ASC;
```

Click Here To Check [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2cd873bdcfe843a3beb6c6f186b35813)

Hopefully you will Undestand It. Feel free to share if you have any query.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how you may simulate a full outer join in MySQL:

```
SELECT a.t, a.x, b.y FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.t = b.t
UNION ALL
SELECT b.t, a.x, b.y FROM a RIGHT JOIN b ON a.t = b.t WHERE a.t IS NULL;
```

The main problems in your current query are that you are doing `SELECT *`, which means that each table will add 2 columns to the select clause (you only want 3).  Also, the lower half of the union should do a null check on the `a` table, as it only is there to add records missed by the upper left join.